# using virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to use virtualbox to play around with different systems.  It worked fine before, but I had to reinstall everything from scratch.

I am getting an error that I don't understand, I have tried to install the package it asked for, but it already said it was up to date, and I used to modprobe command it told me to, but now I am getting an error I don't understand.  Does anyone know what it means and what I can do to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Answer (score 0):

Since it worked before, I suppose your VT setting in BIOS is set to `Enabled`.

Try **disabling** [PAE/NX in the VM Settings -System - Processor](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54479/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabled#latest).

Comment: I disabled it, and tried again, and I still get the same error.  My BIOS has no settings about Virtualization.

Comment: What Computer are you using? VT-x has been around for awhile.